# Unable to execute SSIS packages from VS2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I am trying to execute a SSIS Package  from C#(VS 2017), this SSIS Package has conditional Split in it . but I could run a simple SSIS Package to execute a Procedure.

I am getting the Below error:

> Data Flow Task: The module containing "Conditional Split, clsid {7F88F654-4E20-4D14-84F4-AF9C925D3087}" is not registered or installed correctly.
>
> Data Flow Task: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "Conditional Split;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0".
>
> Data Flow Task: Conditional Split failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.
>
> Data Flow Task: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

**VS 2017 ,SQL Server 2012** With data tools  are installed my machine.

I dont see SQL Server Integration Services in services.msc

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following phrase

> I don't see SQL Server Integration Services in services.msc

I think you should **reinstall or repair** the Integration Services installation.

You must have installed the Integration Services feature when installed SQL Server 2012, SQL Server Data Tools lets you design and deploy SSIS packages it cannot execute packages without having the service installed. Check the following article for more information:

- [Install Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)

---

Before that, you can try one thing, is to change the `TargetServerVersion` from the SSIS project:

```
GoTo Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> TargetServerVersion
```

[image]

And set it to SQL Server 2012